# angular 2 mdDialog

Tags: angular, mddialog

i am trying to set padding = 0 px and i can't.
Here is plnkr, where i css i am trying to set padding: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/vZVYzM5pMBPyGPLX6X1o?p=preview

I am trying to do this in some ways:
Here is css from above:

```
 md-dialog-container{
      padding: 1px !important;
    }
    .mat-dialog-container{
      padding: 1px !important ;
    }
    .cdk-overlay-container .cdk-global-overlay-wrapper
    .cdk-overlay-pane .mat-dialog-container{
      padding: 1px  !important}
    md-dialog-container{
      padding: 1px !important;
    }
```

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/sQOOLX9kQfJmKS1x9GDg?p=preview

Comment: what did you change  ? ))

Comment: Added `styleUrls: ['dialog-overview-example.css']` and `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to component metadata

Comment: maybe you know, how to do the next thing, when i click outsife of dialog, should pop up one more dialog over the first one )